# Ubuntu is no longer loading

Tags: boot, 16.04, mount, encryption, lvm

I have an encrypted SSD which i can't seem to get into anymore.  It is/was the main drive of my computer with the Ubuntu OS installed on it.

I have made a dd of it with `sudo dd if=/dev/sdb5 of=/home/user1/drive.iso` just in case.

As the computer was not loading, i.e. just a black screen after typing in the passphrase, I decided to remove the drive, and usb plug it into a working computer.

When I try to mount it, Ubuntu asks me for the passphrase.  After entering in the passphrase, I get the message:

```
Unable to mount drive Encrypted

The unlocked device does not have a recognisable file system on it
```

The file system was created by the Ubuntu installation disk, when I chose the full disk encryption option when I first installed the OS.

I'm guessing the file system has somehow been corrupted, is it possible to repair the file system?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

To check the file systems on your Linux partitions...

- boot to the GRUB menu (where you select which OS to start)
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb5`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb5`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Please remember to vote/accept my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I think it will only check LVM PV metadata... It might be necessary to fsck LVM logical volume.

Comment: @AndriusŠtikonas my error. I copy/pasted an answer that I typed up 5 minutes before, and forgot to remove the /dev/mapper... stuff.